# existence of certain weak local homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space. Given an arbitrary point $a\in X$ and an open neighborhood $U$ of $a$, does there always exist a continuous real-valued function $f$ on $X$ and an open neighborhood $V$ of $a$ contained in $U$ such that the restriction of $f$ on $V$ is a homeomorphism onto its image?

More generally, given two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, under what conditions the following statement holds: For any point $a\in X$ and any open neighborhood $U$ of $a$, there exists a continuous map $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ such that the restriction of $f$ on $U$ is a homeomorphism onto its image.

PS: OK. Both of the above are not true. So let me weaken the first statement: Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space. Given a point $a\in X$ and an open neighborhood $U$ of $a$, does there exist a continuous real-valued function $f$ on $X$ and an open interval $I$ containing $f(a)$ such that $f^{-1}(I)$ is contained in $U$?

Comment: In your first paragraph, what is the point of introducing $U$ if you're just restricting to $V$ later?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. However, I guess you misunderstood my PS. I revised the PS.

Comment: Misread, not misunderstood, but you’re right, I did.

Comment: The answer is *yes* for any completely regular space and hence for any compact Hausdorff space: by complete regularity there is a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(a)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in X\setminus U$. Now just take $I$ to be any open interval around $0$ that does not include $1$.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. Your answer reminded me of the Urysohn's lemma for locally compact Hausdorff space (I found it in Folland's real analysis book).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $X=\omega_1+1$ with the order topology, and let $a$ be the point $\omega_1$: every continuous $f:X\to\Bbb R$ is constant on some open nbhd of $a$, so no continuous $f:X\to\Bbb R$ can restrict to a homeomorphism on any nbhd of $a$.

**Added:** For another example, let $X=\beta\Bbb N$, and let $a\in\beta\Bbb N\setminus\Bbb N$ be arbitrary. Let $U$ be any open nbhd of $a$. Then, as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/354334/12042), $a$ is not the limit of any sequence in $U$, so $U$ cannot be homeorphic to any subset of $\Bbb R$: every subset of $\Bbb R$ is first countable.